# CPU/Memory Tab Not Showing Up When Profiling With Java Visual VM

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm

When I try to profile my java application with Java VisualVM the Threads, CPU and Memory profiling tabs do not show up. I do not have any JVM arguments for my program apart from "-Djava.library.path=lib/native", is there an specific argument that I need to use to enable profiling?

Other information:

- Built with Netbeans
- Uses LWJGL

Comment: Are you running jvisualvm as the same user that's running the program under test?

Comment: Yes, the program does show up on the side bar. The only things that are missing are the Threads, CPU and Memory profiling tabs

Comment: Are you running the same version of VisualVM as the JVM?  It can be version specific.

Comment: Just ran the VisualVM from the 64 bit jdk and it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just so this will get removed from the `Unanswered` list:

The problem was resolved by running the same version of VisualVM as the JVM (64-bits in this case). The successful profiling can be version specific.

Comment: I also note, to make more clear, that you can't profile an application running under jdk5 when visual vm runs on jdk6+, you will have to run your application with jdk6 in order to see the Profiler tab.